# Normal coordinates vs. Locally flat

Tags: differential-geometry

If $M$ is a Riemannian manifold the inverse function theorem tells us that for any $p \in M$ the exponential map gives us a nieghborhood $U$ of $p$ and normal coordinates $(x^i)$ in which the components of the metric are $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ and the Christoffel symbols vanish at $p$. Why is this not the same as saying $M$ is locally flat?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by locally flat. I think the idea is that a singleton point is not (in general) open set.

Comment: The metric is only $\delta_{ij}$ at the point $p$.  And a point of a manifold is only an open set when the manifold is 0-dimensional.

Comment: @Eric: could you turn your comment into an answer so that the OP can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metric is only $\delta_{ij}$ at the point $p$. And a point of a manifold is only an open set when the manifold is 0-dimensional.

Comment: And the physicists always say $M$ is locally flat, which makes me crazy for days...