# Is every Riemannian metric "locally" flat?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have the following cuestion: Is every Riemannian metric "locally" flat?, i.e., for every poit $p\in M$ there is a smooth chart around $p$ such that the Christoffel symbols are all zero.

If this is true, how can i obtain such chart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are misusing the language. "At a single point" is NOT "locally." Yes, you can make the Christoffel symbols be zero at a point, but not locally. So you know nothing about curvature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true as the curvature is $C^2$-invariant and is determined by the Christoffel symbols.

It is possible to prescribe the metric at a point (this is a matter of linear algebra), but not in an open neighbourhood.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40931/normal-coordinates-vs-locally-flat?rq=1